# state containing an array is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of a particular length stored in a state variable. for example:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([1,1,1])
```

I have a button which will fire a function on click to decrease the length of this array.
I am using `array.pop()` for this.

What I am doing is:

```
const handleRemoveRow = () => {
    let arr = rows;
    console.log("oldArr", arr);
    arr.pop();
    console.log("newArr", arr);
    setRows(arr);
};
```

Problem is, when i console newArr...it prints the array with the decreased length which is the expected result, but my state doesn't updates.

What i am doing wrong.

Here's the reproduction:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-lichterman-95g55?file=/src/App.js:155-306

Comment: CodeSandbox App.js is empty :(

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-lichterman-95g55?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Try this: `useEffect(() => console.log("rows", rows), [rows]);` instead of `useEffect(() => console.log("rows", rows), [rows.length]);`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I've already tried that...it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new instance array with items of rows.

Because if you do `let arr = rows` you get reference from `rows` and assign to `arr`

```js
 const handleRemoveRow = () => {
    let arr = [...rows];
    console.log("oldArr", arr);
    arr.pop();
    console.log("newArr", arr);
    setRows(arr);
};
```

And `useEffect`you could use this:

```js
useEffect(() => console.log("rows", rows), [rows]);
```